# onkeyup not working comparing input javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have copy from [Comparing form input and span value for keyup function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802178/comparing-form-input-and-span-value-for-keyup-function) ,

```
    while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
    ......
        <td><input type="text" name="qtydo[]" value="<?php echo $row['qty'];?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="one_and_done_stool_QTY_remain" required="" disabled ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="one_and_done_stool_QTY_check" maxlength="7" required=""></td>
}
```

js

```
    <script>
document.getElementById('one_and_done_stool_QTY_check').addEventListener('input', Qty_check);


function Qty_check(e) {
    var QTY1check = +document.getElementById('one_and_done_stool_QTY_check').value;
    var QTY1remain = +document.getElementById('one_and_done_stool_QTY_remain').value;

    if (QTY1check > QTY1remain) {
        console.log("NOPE");
        document.getElementById("one_and_done_stool_QTY_check").value = 0;
    }
}
</script>
```

table [not working in second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOVWk.png)

first row succeeds but second row fails , need help.

thanks

Comment: You're using the same ID on multiple elements, IDs are meant to be unique, use class names instead.

Comment: sorry , how to make different ID if row generate from result db and same id with function?

Comment: Can you change the server code ? If so, add class names to the inputs, they don't need IDs.

Comment: change id with class ? already triend not working

Comment: Yes, beside that you'll also have to change the JS to use `getElementsByClassName` and in the `Qty_check` function use the event (`e` object) to determine which input was clicked and get the other input on the same table row.

Comment: @AgustoNice you'll also need to be aware that `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements (not just one), and so you'll need to add your input event listener using a loop (see how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-classA). You could also use the `this` keyword to check which element was clicked as well

Comment: `@Tutus` and `@Nick Parsons`, what is the point of that advice? When possible, just attach the Event to the Element it should be attached to, instead of  testing for `EventObject.target`. I mean... it sounds like you're suggesting to loop over all the inputs, which you wouldn't need to add a class for that, by the way... not to mention the Browser would be doing unnecessary work.